# How can I exclude a jar file from war which is present inside a EAR

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have an ear which contains a war. I want to exclude a jar present in WEB-INF/lib that is present in war. I am using maven-ear-plugin. How can I do that ?

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <finalName>mss-${env}-${pom.version}</finalName>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.mss</groupId>
                            <artifactId>webModule</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/mssapp</contextRoot>
                            <bundleFileName>mssweb-${env}-${pom.version}.war</bundleFileName>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: You have to remove it from the war upfront. Afterwards you can not do that...

Comment: @khmarbaise  I tried excluding the dependency from the war like this but it didn't work. Is this correct?                                                                               
   <dependency>
         <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
         <artifactId>webModule</artifactId>
    <version>${pom.version}</version>
         <type>war</type>
           <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                 <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
                 <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
      </dependency>

Comment: No, you need to do this when **building** the war.

Comment: @JFabianMeier maven-war-plugin is not included in pom.xml.  maven-release-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin are used. Any idea where the war building takes place ?

Comment: It is unlikely that the WAR is build in the same POM as the EAR. It was probably build somewhere else.

Comment: This is how I excluded the jar in pom.xml <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.6</version> <configuration> <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/quartz- 1.5.0.jar</packagingExcludes> </configuration> </plugin>